# What year did the minicon "micro BrickCon" first appear at "BrickCon"?

Tags: history, theme, micro-scale

It seems like minicons (a minicon is a LEGO display consisting of minilander figures looking at miniland scale tables populated by microscale MOCs) are popping up everywhere lately.

The last known sighting was in Melbourne, so the theme has officially gone global. Before it became a theme at LEGO conventions across North America, and now the world.

What year did the first *micro BrickCon* go on display at BrickCon in Seattle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [blog of Tom Aplhin](http://tomalphin.com/2014/10/microscale.html) he mentions regarding Microscale

> Steve Oakes, a long-time LEGO builder in Seattle area started a tradition 4 years ago to re-create the BrickCon Public Convention at a smaller scale. His display is called “Micro BrickCon”

*(Edit: The conversation between Tom and myself was in a loud room with lots of activity. He is correct about everything except the year.)*

After building and displaying an 8.5 foot stern paddle wheel ferry boat at BrickCon 2011, I decided it would be easier to build smaller MOCs. I kicked the idea around for a while, and then came up with the concept of making a micro-con. Mariann Ansunuma, former miniland builder at Legoland, and current maker of awesome microscale Lego jewelry, liked the idea and took me under her wing. I built 2 tables, displays and minilanders to display at BrickCon 2012. I was very pleased when Mariann brought along a third table, displays, and minilanders to add to mine.

After the initial Micro BrickCon MOC was displayed, Mariann, who travels to various cons with her vendor booth, took her portion of the MOC and introduced it to cons across America. It has since become a theme featured across N. America, Canada, Germany, and Australia.

In 2012, the MOC was just a MOC. However, micro BrickCon was so well received, in 2013 it became and remains it's own theme. In 2012 7 builders contributed one thing or another to make the MOC better. In 2013 and 2014, 22 builders contributed, and this year, 2015, 29 builders joined in. 
                                                                 -Major Stackings