# Does anybody have pictures of a minicon?

Tags: history, micro-scale

I first heard of a **minicon** in [this question on LEGO Answers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/what-year-did-the-minicon-micro-brickcon-first-appear-at-brickcon).  I have searched in a variety of ways but I can't find any pictures or more than a side-mention of this on the vast Interwebs.  There is a [sci-fi convention in Minnesota since 1968 (!!)](http://mnstf.org/minicon/) of the same name which adds to the confusion.  :)

So:

- does anyone have pictures of the sort of minicon described?
- does anyone have pictures of the specific minicons mentioned in Seattle or Melbourne?
- can you share these pictures with the world?

It'd be great to see what was described and how close I have come through imagination.

Comment: I have some I can post once I can log on to my PC. My phone hates me, otherwise I'd share them now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three images are from BrickCon 2016.
I've rearranged certain portions of this moc to make a 4 foot square section of Emerald City Comic Con 2016. It's on flickr[vid ECCC](https://www.flickr.com/photos/majorstackings/28145225655/)

[image: BrickCon 2016 MADNESS image]

[image: longshot]

[image: BrickCon 2014]

This image is from BrickCon 2014 and was taken the night before the public viewing... It was almost set up. Once the other builders added their mocs, it was.

Comment: The "head shop" is hilarious.